# Monkeypatching/mocking the HTTPX external requests

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching, httpx

I'm trying to monkeypatch the external request. Here is the code of a web endpoint:

```py
import httpx, json
...
@app.get('/test')
async def view_test(request):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
# sending external request
        api_response = await client.get(
            f'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
            timeout=10,
        )
        resp = api_response.json()
# modifying the result
        resp['foo'] = 0
# forwarding the modified result back to the user
        return HTTPResponse(json.dumps(resp), 200)
```

When user sends a GET request to `/test`, it requests an external API (*JSONPlaceholder*), gets the JSON result and adds `'foo' = 0` to it. After that it forwards the result back to the user.
Here is the Postman result:

```json
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false,
    "foo": 0
}
```

Next, here is my `pytest` code:

```py
import httpx, pytest
...
# The `client` parameter is the fixture of web app
def test_view_test(client, monkeypatch):
    async def return_mock_response(*args, **kwargs):
        return httpx.Response(200, content=b'{"response": "response"}')

    monkeypatch.setattr(httpx.AsyncClient, 'get', return_mock_response)
    _, response = client.test_client.get('/test')
    assert response.json == {'response': 'response', 'foo': 0}
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I used pytest's `monkeypatch` fixture to mock the HTTPX request's result with `{"response": "response"}`.
So basically what I expected is that endpoint adds `'foo' = 0` to my mocked result. But instead it returned `{"response": "response"}` unmodified.
Here's the traceback of `pytest -vv` command:

```
>       assert response.json == {'response': 'response', 'foo': 0}
E       AssertionError: assert {'response': 'response'} == {'response': 'response', 'foo': 0}
E         Common items:
E         {'response': 'response'}
E         Right contains 1 more item:
E         {'foo': 0}
E         Full diff:
E         - {'foo': 0, 'response': 'response'}
E         ?  ----------
E         + {'response': 'response'}
```

Can someone help me with why the endpoint doesn't modify `httpx.AsyncClient().get` mocked result?
I used `sanic==22.9.0` for backend, `httpx==0.23.0` for requests, and `pytest==7.2.0` for testing.

Expected to get `{'response': 'response', 'foo': 0}` instead got `{"response": "response"}` - an unmodified result of mocked httpx response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `sanic-testing` uses `httpx` under the hood. So, when you are monkeypatching `httpx` you are also impacting the test client. Since you only want to mock the outgoing calls we need to exempt those from being impacted.

My comment to @srbssv on Discord was to monkeypatch httpx with a custom function that would inspect the location of the request. If it was the internal Sanic app, proceed as is. If not, then return with a mock object.

Basically, something like this:

```py
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock

import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient, Response
from sanic import Sanic, json


@pytest.fixture
def httpx():
    orig = AsyncClient.request
    mock = AsyncMock()

    async def request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        if "127.0.0.1" in url:
            return await orig(self, method, url, **kwargs)
        return await mock(method, url, **kwargs)

    AsyncClient.request = request
    yield mock
    AsyncClient.request = orig


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = Sanic("Test")

    @app.post("/")
    async def handler(_):
        async with AsyncClient() as client:
            resp = await client.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
            return json(resp.json(), status=resp.status_code)

    return app


def test_outgoing(app: Sanic, httpx: AsyncMock):
    httpx.return_value = Response(201, json={"foo": "bar"})

    _, response = app.test_client.post("")
    assert response.status == 201
    assert response.json == {"foo": "bar"}
    httpx.assert_awaited_once()
```